# installing g++ on ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS causes error

Tags: apt, dependencies

I am running this command: sudo apt install g++
My log output is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 g++ : Depends: g++-9 (>= 9.3.0-3~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Did you remember to run `sudo apt update` first, to make sure your local package catalog is up to date?

Comment: sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y then sudo apt install build-essential

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)